# Eight balls distributed amongst four boxes

Tags: probability, combinatorics

We have 8 balls that are randomly distributed into 4 boxes. Each ball is distributed independently from each other and uniformly among the 4 boxes. The two questions I have are:

(a) What is the expected number of balls in a given box?

(b) What is the probability that there is at least 1 ball in every box?

I'm having problems getting started on these questions and would appreciate hints.

Edit: For (c), I'm attempting to use the Inclusion/Exclusion principle. What I currently have is that

$P(N_i \geq 1) = 1 - \sum \limits_i P(N_i = 0) + \sum \limits_{i<j} P(N_i = N_j = 0) - \sum \limits_{i<j<k} P(N_i = N_j = N_k = 0)$

but the numbers aren't adding up.

Comment: And what have *you* tried so far to answer these two questions you have?

Comment: Sorry, I'll edit the post. I'm looking for hints to get started.

Comment: Well, first hint: for (a), "linearity of expectation."

Comment: I mean, I know that 8 = N1 + N2 + N3 + N4 where Ni is the number of balls in the ith box. Then 8 = 4E(N1), since the expectation in each box is the same as they're randomly distributed. => E(Ni) = 2?

Comment: Fix a box, say the first (without loss of generality). Let $X_1,\dots,X_8$ be the (indicator) random variables defined as $X_i=1$ if the $i$th ball goes into the box, and $0$ otherwise. You then have, for every fixed $1\leq i\leq 8$, that $\mathbb{E}[X_i] =\dots$. Then the number of balls in the first box is $\sum_{i=1}^8 X_i$, and its expectation is...

Comment: So it's still 2.

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) Is the easy question.  There is a $\frac 14$ that any ball ends up in a given box.  Sum this over the number of balls $8\cdot \frac 14 = 2$

b) 1 ball in ever box.  Or no box is empty.

How many ways to distrbute the balls among 4 boxes?  $4^8$
Suppose 1 is empty?  How many ways to distribute the balls among 3 boxes?  $3^8$

Unfortunately we cannot just mulitply by 4 because then there will be double counting of some empty boxes, because I haven't determined that box 1 and only box 1 is empty.

Box #1 is empty?  $\frac {3^8}{4^8}$

Box #1 is empty and box 2 is empty?  $\frac {2^8}{4^8}$

Box #1 is empty and box 3 is empty?  $\frac {1}{4^8}$

P(3 empty boxes) = $4\cdot\frac {1}{4^8}$

P(2 empty boxes) = $6\cdot\frac {2^8}{4^8} -3$ P(3 empty boxes)

P(1 empty box) = $4\cdot\frac {3^8}{4^8} -2$ P(2 empty boxes) - $3$ P(1 empty box) $=\frac {4\cdot 3^8 - 12\cdot 2^8+3\cdot4}{4^8}$

P(no empty boxes) = 1 - P(1 empty box) - P(2 empty boxes) - P(3 empty boxes) = $\frac {4^8 - 4\cdot 3^8 + 6\cdot 2^8-4}{4^8}$

Comment: Okay, cool! That's what I got, but wasn't sure about it.